# rabbitmq pika message not acknowleding

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am able to get my messages from my rabbitmq queue, however after I get the message and send it, I try to acknowledge it straight away, however according to the rabbitmq management UI none of my messages are being acknowledged https://gyazo.com/fb0081faa87eda662f8e3446e58fbd23

and here is my code, I am also running multiple consumers asynchronously however, each consuming a seperate queue

```
class MetricsConsumer(Consumer):
    print 'Metrics consumer started...'

    def handle_payload(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        print "metric"
        json_item = json.loads(body)
        metric_type = json_item['type']
        data = json_item['data']
        print json.dumps(data)
        self.medium.server.invoke('Send', method.delivery_tag, metric_type, json.dumps(data))
        channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
```

Comment: What does this mean `after I get the message and send it` ? Who is getting it from where and sending it where? Is your consumer somehow "forwarding" messages?

Comment: I get the message from the queue and send it to my server via websockets or python signalr client.  I am getting the message from my queue and sending to my server

Comment: But your server is another rabbitmq, same as the one that you are getting message from, or some other third type of server?

Comment: no rabbitmq is running on the same box as my producers and consumers so I get interprocess communication.  The consumers then pop the messages off the queue and send it up to my application server

Comment: Ok. Have you tried auto ACK - just for testing?

Comment: How do you go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know about phython, I use C api, and in a function for consuming queues there is a bool flag

Comment: @cantSleepNow that functionality doesn't seem to be exposed on the python pika module.  I can also see my consumers dropping off and stop working altogether after a period of time.

Comment: Are you using the latest stable pika version (0.10.0)?

Comment: @eandersson yes I am